# Aschbacher Class $2$ subgroup structure

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, magma-cas, maximal-subgroup, wreath-product

In $PGL(12,3)$, there should be an Aschbacher Class $2$ subgroup the image of $GL(2,3)^6 \wr{\rm Sym}(6)$. I am trying to locate the image of $GL(2,3)^6$ in Magma using derived subgroup but it doesn't seem to be doing the job.

```
     X:=GL(12,3);
     G:=PGL(12,3);
     ro:=hom<X->G|G.1,G.2>;
     d:=ClassicalMaximals("L",12,3:general:=true,classes:={2});
     #ro(d[4]);
    
     M4:=ro(d[4]);
     DER:=DerivedSubgroup(M4);
     #DER;
     1100753141760
     DER1:=DerivedSubgroup(DER);
     #DER1;
     1100753141760
```

Which part went wrong? How do I locate the desired part then? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your approach at all. The group ${\rm Sym}(6)$ is not solvable so repeatedly taking derived groups will never eliminate the composition factor ${\rm Alt}(6)$.

Comment: I finally understand it now why taking derived subgroups.  Then how should I locate this part? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the kernel of the imprimitive action in the group $\mathtt{d[4]}$.

```
> d:=ClassicalMaximals("L",12,3:general:=true,classes:={2});
> H := d[4]; ng := Ngens(H); ng;
4
> IsPrimitive(H);
false
> rho := hom< H->Sym(6) | [ImprimitiveAction(H,H.i) : i in [1..4]] >;
> K := Kernel(rho);
> isiso := IsIsomorphic(K, DirectProduct([GL(2,3): i in [1..6]])); isiso;
true
```

Comment: I've learned two knowledge points.

Comment: Alternatively, you can get $K$ as $\mathtt{ncl<H\, | \,H.1,H.2>)}$, but the method in the above code is safer in general.

Comment: OK. Thank you for that. Is ncl short for number of class?

Comment: No, it means normal closure. The generators of the class 2 maximal subgroups of classical groups generally consist of generators of one of the factors of the base group (${\rm GL}(2,3)$ in this case), followed by generators of the top group ($S_6$).